# Async actions - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I know the logic of asynchronous methods, but I do not understand how the following method gives me advantages. Is the following asynchronous method different from a synchronous method?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Instead of *blocking* a thread waiting for a database to respond, the server releases the thread for other work. When the database responds, the server picks up processing after the `await`. On a web server with moderate traffic that means that more requests can be server by the same number of threads.

Comment: CPU usage also goes down because blocking operations aren't no-ops, as you'll notice from Performance Monitor. On the one hand, a blocking operation starts with a spinwait before a thread is put to sleep, thus wasting CPU. On the other hand, the OS has to check each sleeping thread to find which got unblocked. Thus, you get CPU load for nothing

Comment: In short, async operations allow you to serve more requests from the same hardware

Comment: All the descriptions are very clear. I now understand better.

Comment: @Cer: I wrote an article on [async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) that you may find useful. It explains why asynchronous handlers for I/O are better than synchronous ones, complete with pretty pictures.

Comment: @StephenCleary Nice article. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the benefits of this practice, first we need to understand how the ASP.NET lifecycle works.

Every time we make a request to the server, the pipeline retrieves a thread pool thread to handle it and as with every resource there are limits to how many threads are available for this purpose in the thread pool.

Some operations, such as I/O or database operations, generally block the processing, lasting longer than expected.

When the pipeline reaches the limit of available resources, all it can do is wait until some of them get released so that it can process new requests.

When the await/async approach gets in to action, because of its internal workings, the runtime can handle these tasks asynchronously, releasing the thread pool thread to process another request while the previous one is being blocked. This generally results in higher overall throughput using the same available resources at the cost of slightly higher processing costs per individual request.

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/creating-asynchronous-actions-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) a simple explanation about that.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Async method will not change anything from client perspective. It will be normal http call (with almost same time to complete request). However you will get better scale on your web server.

Ex- for following lines in your code, whenever any async operation is in progress worker thread (which is processing request) will be returned to thread pool. That thread is free to process next request. When async operation completes then thread will be picked from thread pool for further processing.

```
var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);

// and other async methods
```

To test this you can run a scale test on this api and cross check number of calls served by async controller vs sync controller.

For more detailed information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Hope this help.